# Cannot install TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter Archer T4UHP on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless, tp-link

I have a TP-LINK Wireless USB adapter, which in the box is advertised as "Archer T4UHP".

Running just released Ubuntu 18.04.1 with kernel 4.15.0-29

Cannot make the USB Adapter to work after trying several alternatives found googling

The output from lsusb is:

```
diego@kush:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0042 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2357:0122  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5149:13d3  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm pretty sure the adapter is the second line (Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2357:0122)

Tried downloading the driver from https://static.tp-link.com/Archer%20...1213_Linux.zip (which says Operating System: Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.19.3) so it's pretty old) but 'make' is returning an error:

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
----- extra_cflags=-DCONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211=1 -DRTW_USE_CFG80211_STA_EVENT=1  -O1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -I/include -I/platform -DCONFIG_RTL8812A -DCONFIG_MP_INCLUDED -DCONFIG_POWER_SAVING -DCONFIG_TRAFFIC_PROTECT -DCONFIG_LOAD_PHY_PARA_FROM_FILE -DREALTEK_CONFIG_PATH="" -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_MODE=0 -DCONFIG_BR_EXT '-DCONFIG_BR_EXT_BRNAME=br0' -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/build M=/home/diego/Downloads/Archer T4UHP(UN)_V1_161213_Linux/8812au  modules
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:1635: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After researching and trying, the solution came from jeremy31 on ubuntuforums.org (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358876&p=13787798#post13787798).
All the credit goes to him.

The device TPLINK Archer T4UHP Wireless USB Adapter apparently uses RTL8812 chipset, so the answer was loading the proper driver.

Just copying the solution here in case it helps others with the same issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU-8821AU_linux
sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install
```

Check Secure Boot status with

```
mokutil --sb-state
```

Reboot and disable Secure Boot if above command reported Secure Boot in use (you need to sudo apt-get install mokutil if its not installed)

I just followed this solution and now my TPLINK Archer T4UHP is working like a charm.